# Set Visual Studio default JSON conversor

Tags: visual-studio, using, jsonserializer

Our project started with `Newtonsoft.Json` and now we are gradually moving to `System.Text.Json.Serialization`.

Whenever I write a new `JsonSerializer.Serialize` or `[JsonIgnore]` line, Visual Studio automatically add `using Newtonsoft.Json;` at the top (if not present yet).

As we are moving away from this, I prefer Visual Studio to set `System.Text.Json.Serialization` or maybe `using JsonSerializer = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer;`.

Is it possible to change this behaviour?